# Why does moving a div shock so much

Tags: jquery, css

Why do images / div shock so much when moving?

```
<div>*</div>
```

```js
$(function() {    
    var fps = 30;
    var a = 0;

    draw = function() {
        a += 0.001;  
        var x = ((Math.cos(a)+1) /2) *90;
        var y = ((Math.sin(a)+1) /2) *90;

        $("div").css("left", x + "%");
        $("div").css("top", y + "%");
    }

    update_frame = function(fps) {
        draw();
        setTimeout(function(){
            update_frame(fps)
        }, (1000./fps));
    }

    update_frame(fps);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/gx4xp1vx/

Comment: also you can play with a's increment value like a += 0.01;

Comment: @tanaydin that would make the movement faster, not smoother.

Comment: Can't you just use css animations using `translate3d`. The uses hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by 'shock' you mean that the movement isn't smooth. If this is the case just up the `fps` value.

```
var fps = 100;
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gx4xp1vx/3/)

The trade-off here is that a faster refresh rate takes more processing power, which may be more noticeable when moving several elements, or those containing imagery - especially on slower systems.